# mysqlWorkbench Error : Unhandled exception: new-line character seen in unquoted field

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Can anyone please help fix this Error?

Task:  I am trying to import data from a csv file

mysqlWorkbench Error : Unhandled exception: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode? Check the log for more details.

[image]

Comment: You should add more details

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to import data from a csv file

Comment: Did you take a look at the log?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: 
All I had to do was to save the ccv file as a Windows csv even though I was doing so from a Mac.